# How should I proceed to classify images of not ok microchips

Tags: machine-learning, python, supervised-learning, pattern-recognition

So I have a new project where I have to classify different types of damages on microchips. I am new to machine learning and python in general so I am a little bit lost. I have over 100.000 images I can use as training-data. But these images are not labeled. My first question is, how do I label these images? I couldn't find a suiting tutorial for my problem. I found the labeling Tool supervise and it seems to be cool, but is it right? By the way these are some examples of the microchips:
[image: scratch]

In this picture for example we see a scratch.

[image: scratch]

this chip has another scratch on it.
[image: broken edge]

Here we can see that the edge is a little bit broken (the microchip is rotated).

Another problem is that the microchips are not always centered and rotated. The rotation is no problem because I could orientate the images with the dot on the left. And the positioning of the images should be no problem too if I cut out the microchip from the carrier?

So I have an idea of how I want to classify the images. But I don't know how to start..

I have also seen an article/tutorial, where for every Class a folder is made and the images of this Class are added in these folders. In my Case every Picture is the same object, just little differences are seen, so I think the seperation of these images is not so good. Scratches, broken edges, bad lasermarkings or false serial numbers are classification cases.